# weblogic 12.2.1 deployment issue

Tags: nullpointerexception, weblogic12c

I am getting NPE while trying to deploy ear file in WL 12.2.1 server. The ear gets deployed without issue in Weblogic 12.1.3. Here is the error log. 
Being trying to resolve this for few days without any success. Any idea why NPE comes from WebLogic packages?

> Error::  "Deployer BEA-149265 Failure occurred in the execution of
>   deployment request with ID "17802533653132"for task "1" on
>   [partition-name: DOMAIN].
>
> Error is: "weblogic.utils.ErrorCollectionException:
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794: There are 2 nested errors:
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794: weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.work.ContextWrap.run(ContextWrap.java:46)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:666)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)"
>
> "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1011)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1006)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.spring.monitoring.instrumentation.SpringClassPreprocessor.createSpringInstrumentorEngineIfNecessary(SpringClassPreprocessor.java:67)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.spring.monitoring.instrumentation.SpringClassPreprocessor.(SpringClassPreprocessor.java:26)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.spring.monitoring.instrumentation.SpringInstrumentationUtils.addSpringInstrumentor(SpringInstrumentationUtils.java:87)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppInternalModuleExtension$SpringInstrumentationExtension.doInstrumentation(WebAppInternalModuleExtension.java:113)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppInternalModuleExtension$SpringInstrumentationExtension.access$400(WebAppInternalModuleExtension.java:102)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppInternalModuleExtension.prePrepare(WebAppInternalModuleExtension.java:57)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:293)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:285)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:109)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     ... 13 more
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794: and
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794: weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextStateInParallel(StateMachineDriver.java:144)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.parallelPrepare(ModuleStateDriver.java:46)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:75)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:55)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:727)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:239)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:66)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:65)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:229)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:103)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:241)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:794)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1340)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:267)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:177)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:186)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:47)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:666)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
>        [java] WLST-WLS-1529953358794:     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the solution was found, it was issue with the jar antlr-2.7.6.jar packaged with the ear file conflicting with the default class loader. 
Solution : -Changed the weblogic.xml to add antlr package to be loaded from an application and not from default class loader.

Comment: You probably meant the weblogic-application.xml (prefer-application-packages tag)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution : adding

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
```

… at `setDomainEnv.cmd`  also worked for me